# What can you do with UART ports in Microcontroller?

Tags: uart

In my Microcontroller there exist UART ports. But I have not understood well how they can be used. Can I use them for TTL or RS232 communication? And would it be also possible for me to use them to receive DVP signal from CMOS image sensor like OV7670?

Thank you

Comment: Microcontroller UARTs can not do RS232 by themselves, so they need an external RS232 transceiver IC to do RS232.  Related: [Difference between UART and RS232?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110478/difference-between-uart-and-rs232).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UART is a communication protocol. If micro controller wants to communicate to a specific sensor which supports UART then the micro controller can be interfaced to that sensor using UART protocol.

In your micro controller you have specific Tx(Transmitting) and Rx(Receiving) pins. If you go through your controllers datasheet or pinouts you will get it.
OV7670 works with UART interface. Your connection should be like this
OV7670 Tx----Micro controller Rx
OV7670 Rx----Micro controller Tx
OV7670 Gnd---Micro controller Gnd

If you are going to connect the micro controller to PC or any other RS232 devices then you may need to convert TTL logic to RS232 logic. You have many readily available converters for this purposes.

Comment: Thank you. So the difference between TTL and RS232 is just max/min voltage Isn't it?

Comment: Not exactly. Like what kind of voltage are you referring to? Can you be precise?

Comment: Hope this helps you
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-OV7670-Camera-Module-with-Arduino/